# Powershell Export-Csv with no header row

Tags: powershell

I have created custom data object that I output to csv.  It all works fine, but how do I strip the header row from the output file?  I've tried some variations of the "Select -Skip", but that usually generates a blank csv file.  Here is the relevant bits of code:

```
#populate data row with user properties
$DataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'EventID'-Value $EventID 
$DataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Computer'-Value $env:COMPUTERNAME 
$DataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'EngineerID' -Value $EngineerID
$DataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'UserID' -Value $UserID
$DataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'DateTime' -Value $DateTime
$DataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'StepCode' -Value $StepCode
$DataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Result' -Value $Result
$DataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Status' -Value $HomeDirectoryAccess

#export the dataobject to a CSV file
$OutputFile = ($OutFilePath + "\Status_" + $env:COMPUTERNAME + "_" + $DateStamp + "-" + $TimeStamp + ".csv")
$DataObject | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

The $DataObject looks like this:

```
EventID    : Test
Computer   : MD-760R102
EngineerID : Jez
UserID     : laijer
DateTime   : 25/03/2015 12:24 PM
StepCode   : USH
Result     : Complete
Status     : Home Drive Access Allowed
```

I've also tried this code to output the data, but it puts all the data into the 1st cell of the csv file instead of individual cells across a single row:

```
$DataOutput = $DataObject.EventID + "," + $DataObject.Computer + "," + $DataObject.EngineerID + "," + $DataObject.UserID + "," + $DataObject.DateTime + "," + $DataObject.StepCode + "," + $DataObject.Result + "," + $DataObject.Status
$DataOutput | Out-File $OutputFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `ConvertTo-CSV` and `Select -Skip 1` together to get what you want. You'll have to split on new lines after converting to CSV, since it outputs a multi-line string, but that's simple enough.

```
($DataObject | Select EventID,Computer,EngineerID,UserID,DateTime,StepCode,Result,Status | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation).split("`n") | select -skip 1 | set-content $OutputFile
```

That will give you the following:

```
"Test","MD-760R102","Jez","laijer","25/03/2015 12=24 PM","USH","Complete","Home Drive Access Allowed"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you so much.

Comment: lol sorry, was looking all over the place for a "Mark as answer" button, just realised the "tick" symbol under the down vote arrow was it.