# PowerShell Export-Csv No Headers

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I'm attempting to create multiple CSV files with no headers using `Export-Csv` within a PowerShell script. I've read a few posts about using the `Select-Object -Skip 1` trick, but I haven't gotten it to successfully work on my code. Here's how I tried to call it:

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\$($csvname[$i])_$timer.csv"
```

Here's my full, functioning code:

```
function Run-Query {
    Param([string[]]$queries,[string[]]$csvname)
    Begin {
        $SQLServer = 'myserver'
        $Database = 'mydatabase'
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True"
        $timer = (Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
    } # End Begin
    Process {
        # Loop through each query
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $queries.Count; $i++) {
            $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

            # Use the current index ($i) to get the query
            $SqlCmd.CommandText = $queries[$i]
            $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
            $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
            $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
            $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
            $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

            # Use the current index ($i) to get the sheetname for the CSV
            $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\$($csvname[$i])_$timer.csv"
        }
    } # End Process
    End {
        $SqlConnection.Close()
    }
} # End function run-query.

#Entery Query
$queries = @()
$queries += @'
SELECT * FROM table2
'@
$queries += @'
SELECT * FROM table1
'@

#List of CSV file names.
$csvname = @()
$csvname += 'file1'
$csvname += 'file2'
Run-Query -queries $queries -csvname $csvname
```

Comment: The `Select-Object -skip 1` "trick" is for _importing_ CSVs as text files rather than as objects. You can't export a CSV without the header information. Why do you want to? The definition of the CSV format includes the headers.

Comment: It's required for the 3rd party that I'm transferring the file to. There's no way to get around this with powershell?

Comment: @Joe Your 3rd party requires a comma separated file without headers?  How do they know what any of the fields mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell export-csv with no headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389952/powershell-export-csv-with-no-headers) or [Powershell Export-Csv with no header row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29246005/150605)

Comment: Your only choices are to either manually compose your comma-separated lines and write them out as a text file, or write it out to a tempfile using Export-CSV, then read the tempfile as a text file (e.g., with `Get-Content`), dropping the first line, and writing it back out without that first line. Or see the questions that @BACON linked to.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, I know your comment is old. But I just want to ask you (and anyone else who might know) anyway. Why did you say the definition of the CSV format includes the headers?
I can see RFC4180 ( https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 ) treats header thing as optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how CSVs work in PowerShell. Assume you have a CSV file with the following content:

```
foo,bar,baz
A,1,2
B,3,4
```

Importing that CSV via `Import-Csv` will give you 2 objects with the properties `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` filled with the values from one data row each. Using JSON notation the list of objects would look like this:

```json
[
    {
        "foo": "A",
        "bar": "1",
        "baz": "2"
    },
    {
        "foo": "B",
        "bar": "3",
        "baz": "4"
    }
]
```

`Export-Csv` does basically the same, just in reverse. I takes objects as input and writes the values of their properties to the fields of the CSV. The fields are determined by the properties of the first object `Export-Csv` receives. If one of these properties is missing in a subsequent object a NULL value is written to the respective field. If a subsequent object has additional properties that the first object didn't have they are ignored.

Using `Select-Object -Skip 1` with either `Import-Csv` or `Export-Csv` is useless, because normally you don't want to skip any of the input or output objects (otherwise you'd lose data).

There are, however, two other cmdlets similar to `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` that read and write strings rather than files: `ConvertFrom-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Csv`. `Import-Csv` is basically a combination of `Get-Content` and `ConvertFrom-Csv`, and `Export-Csv` a combination of `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Set-Content`.

So, where does `Select-Object -Skip 1` come into play here? When you convert your object input to CSV via `ConvertTo-Csv` and skip the first row of the string output, you effectively remove the header line from the output text, something you couldn't do with `Export-Csv`.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $data = @()
PS C:\> $data += [PSCustomObject]@{"foo"="A"; "bar"="1"; "baz"="2"}
PS C:\> $data += [PSCustomObject]@{"foo"="B"; "bar"="3"; "baz"="4"}
PS C:\> $data | Format-Table -Auto

foo bar baz
--- --- ---
A   1   2
B   3   4

PS C:\> $data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType
"foo","bar","baz"
"A","1","2"
"B","3","4"
PS C:\> $data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select-Object -Skip 1
"A","1","2"
"B","3","4"
```

Pipe that output into `Set-Content` and you have the headerless CSV files you want.

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoType |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Set-Content "C:\$($csvname[$i])_$timer.csv"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Works perfectly to APPEND content to an existing CSV file with `Add-Content` or `Out-File -Append` - I haven't seen anyone mention that use case so thought I'd comment for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to output CSV input objects as tab-separated data without headers:

```
function ConvertTo-Tsv {
  param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [Object[]] $Object
  )
  process {
    foreach ( $objectItem in $Object ) {
      ($objectItem.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value) -join "`t"
    }
  }
}
```

You could then do either of the following:

```
Import-Csv "inputfile.csv" | ConvertTo-Tsv
```

or

```
$data = Import-Csv "inputfile.csv"
ConvertTo-Tsv $data
```

Comment: I added "Import-Csv "$($csvname[$i])_$timer.csv" | ConvertTo-Tsv" right under my "Export-Csv" line. This drastically increased the execution time of the script, but didn't seem to have any affect on the headers.

Comment: The function provided by this answer is a good solution, but the examples for how to use it are misleading.  The source of the data is an SQL database, not another CSV file so there's no need to use `Import-Csv`.  Instead, replace `Export-Csv` with `ConvertTo-Csv` like so: `$DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Tsv | Set-Content -Path "C:\$($csvname[$i])_$timer.csv"`

Comment: Correct, my example is generic (referring to CSV) -- it's assumed that the user is responsible for passing the correct objects into the pipeline for the function.